# How to derive correct result when overflow occurs in 2's Complement Addition?

Tags: binary, overflow, addition, integer-overflow, signed-integer

we can always detect overflow in 2's complement addition by certain pre-defined rules, but my question is that can I somehow find out the correct result whenever overflow condition occurs in system?

> we all know the Overflow detection process in signed representation of number is as follows:
> Two negative numbers are added and an answer comes positive or
> Two positive numbers are added and an answer comes as negative then overflow happens

But my intention is to find out the correct result if possible in overflow condition.